# Why do I get a type error when trying to change value of tkinter's entry boxes to numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter

```
a = IntVar(root, aEntry.get())
b = IntVar(root, bEntry.get())
c = IntVar(root, cEntry.get())

y = a*x**2 + b*x + c
```

This gives me this error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'IntVar' and 'float'". If it helps, I am trying to use that equation to draw a quadratic graph using numpy and matplotlib.

Comment: What's a IntVar`?  Is multiply defined for it?

Comment: @hpaulj `tk.IntVar`

Answer (score 1):

You're multiplying the `IntVar` object itself, which is wrong.

Instead, you want to multiply the value that is stored *inside* the `IntVar`.  Use `.get()` to fetch the value.

```
y = a.get() * x**2 + b.get() * x + c.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `IntVar` at all, just convert the content from those entries to integer:

```py
try:
    a = int(aEntry.get())
    b = int(bEntry.get())
    c = int(cEntry.get())

    y = a * x**2 + b * x + c
except ValueError as ex:
    print(ex)
```